# What is the canonical way to pause WinCMD-Style in Linux Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, zsh

In **Windows** Batch/CMD, to pause the execution of a script, you would use

```
echo 'This is before pause.'
pause
echo 'The key was pressed, continuing...'
```

How would this be realised using a standard terminal like say `bash` (but `zsh` or others should also work at best)? I could of course write an easy `C` application, but I can't believe, that there is no canonical way - `sleep` is not, what I'm looking for.

I found these straight-forward approaches using [read](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/read.htm):

- `read -p 'Press [Enter] key to start backup...'`
- `read -p 'Press any key to resume ...'`
- `read -s -n 1 -p 'Press any key to continue . . .'` [inside a function](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Writing_your_first_shell_function)

but they give me `XXX.sh: 4: read: arg count` for the first two or `3: read: Illegal option -n` respectively. I'm using bash `4.4.19(1)-release`.

Comment: You can also consider [this SO-Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/226703/4575793)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read_a_key() (
  exec </dev/tty
  t=$(stty -g)
  trap 'stty "$t"; return' EXIT INT QUIT TERM 
  stty raw -echo isig
  dd count=1 2>/dev/null
)

printf '%s ' 'Press ANY KEY to continue ... '
key=$(read_a_key)
echo OK, continuing
```

Use it as `read_a_key >/dev/null` if you don't care what key the user had pressed.

This should also work fine with keys which turn into multiple characters (as e.g. `F1`), unlike bash's `read -n1`, which will leave over spurious `OP` or `[[A` characters for the next command ;-)

Comment: Note that in shells like `bash`, if you intercept SIGINT and exit normally in a child process, then the script won't exit upon `^C` (same for SIGQUIT vs ^\ ). To work around that, you'd need to replace that `return` with a `kill -s INT <mypid>` (where `<mypid>` is the pid of the subshell (but beware not all shells run subshells in a child process)).

Comment: As you're reading the key from the controlling tty (`/dev/tty`), you may want to issue the prompt there as well instead of stdout which may be redirected (or maybe stderr).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it's even more broken than that. a) it doesn't handle TSTP/CONT b) it calls `stty "$t"` twice c) it doesn't work in `yash`. I've tried to do something that work in as many shells as possible (thence the awkward `return`), but the results are still less than stellar ;-) A version which do WCE correctly *but* only work in bash would not catch the `INT`, `QUIT` and `TERM` at all, but rely on bash running the `EXIT` trap even when terminating because of a signal.

Answer (score 4):

The main reason your `read` commands don't work is that they are for `bash` but you're using `sh`.

The [cited article](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/read.htm) says,

> On Unix-like operating systems, `read` is a builtin command of the `bash` shell

It is also a builtin command in many other shells, including the `sh` that you're using, but the syntax for `read` in `sh` is much less rich.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
read -p 'Press [Enter] key to continue: '
...
```

Remember to make the file executable and then run it as a program

```
# Assume the script is called "demo"
chmod a+x demo
./demo
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the `-p` flag doesn’t appear in POSIX, either; [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) only defined the `-r` flag. The `-p` flag just happens to be implemented by many shells, including Dash and BusyBox.

Comment: @FranklinYu, `-p` in ksh (from the early 80s and a subset of which bash is mostly a clone of) or zsh is to read from the co-process so it will likely never make it into POSIX. To issue a prompt, it's `read 'var?prompt'` there.

Answer (score 4):

In plain sh, there's no easy way to wait for a single key press. It's a lot easier to ask the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, because there's an easy way to wait for the user to enter a line.

The `read` built-in command reads a line. You need to give it the name of a variable to store the content of the line, even if you aren't going to use it.

```
echo 'Press Enter to continue.'
read -r line
echo 'Continuing.'
```

If your script starts with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` or equivalent, `read` has additional options that let it wait for a single key press. I don't think it's worth bothering with it, and teaching your users which keys do or do not count as “any key”.

Note that it is very common to run scripts unattended and with no terminal on Unix-like systems. Typical servers have nobody logged in on the console most of the time. So asking the user to confirm something is very uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

I found a comment by user *epileg* on a site suggesting [this code snippet](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-pause-command.html?unapproved=24613&moderation-hash=da87cb63a13e8d2bab79a8d9a840b022&comment=24613#comment-10558) (slightly edited), claiming that "there is a way to cleanly do that on Linux:"

```
#!/bin/bash
...
echo -n 'Press <ENTER> to continue...'
stty -echo
dd count=1 1>/dev/null 2>&1
stty echo
echo #Produces an empty line in the end, can be removed.
...
```

While obvious to some users, it should also be mentioned, that the shebang `#!/bin/bash` doesn't decide what is used if you do. Let's say the above script was called demo and you typed `sh demo` or `zsh demo`, `sh` or `zsh` are called respectively, not `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with:

```
read -p 'press Enter ...'
```

but if you get that arg_count error, you are not using bash but another shell. Fix: just add an argument, e.g.:

```
read -p 'press Enter ...' x
```

Now it should work in your shell. The extra argument can be a dummy name, or exploited to hold the user answer, e.g.:

```
echo You answered: $x
```

Comment: `-p` is for bash. Most other shells use `read 'var?prompt'` to specify a prompt when they do have a way to specify a prompt. The only standard option to `read` is `-r`.